# Is there any way to find average in excel file for a particular sample

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have large excel file of such sample data as given below, randomly placed:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 825 | Sample1 |
| 825 | Sample1 |
| 825 | Sample1 |
| 729 | Sample1 |
| 729 | Sample1 |
| 729 | Sample1 |
| 3114 | Sample1 |
| 1158 | Sample1 |
| 633 | Sample1 |
| 3105 | Sample1 |
| 3105 | Sample1 |
| 3105 | Sample1 |
| 3105 | Sample2 |
| 1158 | Sample2 |
| 1158 | Sample2 |
| 1158 | Sample2 |
| 1158 | Sample2 |
| 663 | Sample2 |

I want average for each sample. Please help how to do it. To get the average in one go without doing it manually for each sample.

There are at least 500 samples so applying  formula may help.

Comment: look into `AVERAGEIF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put headers above the list, then insert a Pivottable with the sample as Row header and the average value as Data element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is still only available to Beta users:
`=GROUPBY(B2:B19,A2:A19,AVERAGE,,0)`

Otherwise you could get the unique Samples and then calculate their Averages:

`=UNIQUE(TOCOL(B:B,1))` in `D2` for instance
and `=AVERAGEIF(B:B,D2#,A:A)` in `E2`

or in one go:

`=LET(d,A2:B19,u,UNIQUE(DROP(d,,1)),HSTACK(u,AVERAGEIF(DROP(d,,1),u,TAKE(d,,1))))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNIQUE` to find all samples:

```
=UNIQUE(B1:B18)
```

`AVERAGEIF` to get averages:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B1:B18,UNIQUE(B1:B18),A1:A18)
```

You can `HSTACK` it to get result in one go:

```
=LET(z,UNIQUE(B1:B18),HSTACK(z,AVERAGEIF(B1:B18,z,A1:A18)))
```

or

```
=LET(z,TOCOL(UNIQUE(B:B),1),HSTACK(z,AVERAGEIF(B:B,z,A:A)))
```

To use whole column references.

Result:

[image]